Are all the numbers obtained from this process for a subset of rational numbers the same?!
For every subset $A$ of the additive group of rational numbers with $1\in A$, put $D:=A-A$ and $C:=\mathbb{Q}\setminus D$. Set $b_0:=0$ and construct the (finite or infinite) sequences
$\{b_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ as follows:
By the assumption $b_0,\cdots , b_{n}$ are defined, for every integer $n\geq 0$,  choose an  element $b_{n+1}$ in $C\cap (b_1+C)\cap\cdots\cap (b_n+C)$  if it is nonempty (equivalentely $D\cup (b_1+D)\cup\cdots\cup (b_n+D)\neq \mathbb{Q}$).
Denote by $N$ the least integer $N\geq 0$ such that $C\cap (b_1+C)\cap\cdots\cap (b_N+C)=\emptyset$ if there is such $N$, otherwise define $N:=\infty$.
A challenging and interesting question is whether the number $N$ in the above algorithm is independent of the choices of $b_n$'s.
If not, are the obtained values ​​for $N$ all finite or all infinite?
Note. It is easy to check that if $A$ (resp. $A-A$) is a subgroup, then $N=|\mathbb{Q}:A|$
(resp. $N=|\mathbb{Q}:A-A|$). Hence $N$ is independent of the choices of $b_n$'s.
Also, it can be shown that if there is any counterexample for it, $A$ should be a subset of the form  this.
It is worth noting that $A$ and $B:=\{ b_0,b_1,\cdots \}$ satisfy the conditions of this.
One can find more information in this and this.
Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Do you happen to be a German speaker? "bzw." should almost never be translated directly as "respectively", which has different uses in English and does not take the place of a conjunction. Also "resp." is not a common English abbreviation. Usually just "or" or "and" is needed. When there's more than one list with corresponding items, we can say they match one for one by placing comma and "respectively" after the second list: "if $A$ (or $A-A$) is a subgroup, then $N = |\mathbb{Q}:A|$ (or $|\mathbb{Q}: A-A|$, respectively)"

No, anyway, thank you very much for your grammar point.

@aschepler it is a fairly common abbreviation in mathematical literature.

Let $A = \bigcup\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \left[n - \frac{1}{7}, n + \frac{1}{7}\right]$. Then $D = \bigcup\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \left[n - \frac{2}{7}, n + \frac{2}{7}\right]$.
If $b_1 = \frac{1}{2}$, then already $D \cup (D + b_1) = \mathbb Q$. However, if $b_1 = \frac{5}{14}$, then $D \cup (D + b_1) = \bigcup\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \left[n - \frac{2}{7}, n + \frac{9}{14}\right] \neq \mathbb Q$.
Similar construction can be used to get possible range of $N$ to be $[k, 2k]$ for any $k$.

Thanks for your interesting answer. Do you know an example with $N_1<\infty$ and $N_2=\infty$?
